# How to spy on an imported function with Cypress in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, testing, cypress

In Cypress when spying on a function, the syntax is cy.spy(object, method), but I would like to spy on a function imported from another file that isn't in an object. Is this possible?

Note: I've tried the following way as well, which doesn't seem to work.

```
//import { func } from 'src/file';
import * as funcObj from 'src/file';

describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    cy.spy(funcObj, 'func');
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Yea, when I tried that I got a type error, saying I was trying to set an undefined property as a function. Like it couldn't tell that 'func' was a function it seemed.

Comment: Can you export an object `src/file`, with `func` being a function on that exported object?

Comment: That's a good point, yes I can do that, and it does work. Although, it isn't ideal since I would be making a new object with only one function, just to fit the spy syntax. But if there isn't any other way, then I'll use this I guess. Thanks!

Comment: How are you importing `func` in the actual implementation? Are you also `import * as funcObj from 'src/file';` or are you doing `import { func } from 'src/file';`?

Comment: I am just doing `import { func } from 'src/file';` currently, but I also tried doing `import * as funcObj from 'src/file';`, like in the example code to use funcObj as the class, which didn't work.

Comment: What was your solution? I encountered the same problem and haven't solved it yet.

Comment: I believe the only way is to create an object and put that function inside it. Then export that object and use the cy.spy(object, method) syntax as normal.